# CSV to Python Dict

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

i have this csv:

```
ref,columns,start,end,content
1,Column1,1234,5654,text11
1,Column2,2454,3223,text12
1,Column3,7565,8765,text13
1,Column4,8524,5456,text14
1,Column5,1235,5245,text15
2,Column1,7856,2356,text21
2,Column2,4568,3545,text22
2,Column3,5756,4563,text23
2,Column4,9856,2135,text24
2,Column5,4535,5456,text25
3,Column1,5756,9856,text31
3,Column2,5764,8778,text32
3,Column3,1536,8768,text33
3,Column4,6861,5654,text34
3,Column5,6875,6586,text35
```

how do i change it into a dictionnary like this?
to make 'ref' to be a column too, and to remove start and end in the output.

```
thisdict = {
  "ref": [1,2,3],
  "Column1": ['text11','text21','text31'],
  "Column2": ['text12','text22','text32'],
  "Column3": ['text13','text23','text33'],
  "Column4": ['text14','text24','text34'],
  "Column5": ['text15','text25','text35'],
}
```

this is what i've tried:

```
    Columns = "Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4","Column5"
    cols = col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 = [],[],[],[],[]

    with open(csvfile,'r',encoding="utf8") as f:
        reader = list((csv.reader(f)))
        for line in reader:
            for i,col in enumerate(Columns):
                if col == line[1]:
                    cols[i].append(line[4])
    for col in cols:
        print(col)
```

outputs:

```
['text11', 'text21', 'text31']
['text12', 'text22', 'text32']
['text13', 'text23', 'text33']
['text14', 'text24', 'text34']
['text15', 'text25', 'text35']
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your code a little bit. Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

col_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open(csvfile,'r',encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        col_dict[row['columns']].append(row['content'])
        if int(row['ref']) not in col_dict['ref']:
            col_dict['ref'].append(int(row['ref']))

print(col_dict)
```

`csv.DictReader` allows you to read each row of your csv as a dictionary. This is possible because your csv has headers.

`defaultdict` allows you to create a dictionary in which the values will default to whatever literal or function you pass to it, in this case `list`, which creates an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

path_to_file = "xxxxxx"
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file)
df = df.reset_index()
del df['Start']
del df['End']

this_dict = df.to_dict()
```

Comment: wouldn't installing pandas for such a simple purpose be overkill?

Comment: Not in my opinion

Comment: Some explanation as to how and why to use this solution would be better than a code-only answer.

Comment: I’m not sure what needs to be explained, it’s a pretty simple script to follow…

Comment: Assuming that OP has any knowledge on pandas, yes it is, but you can't assume that. What does `reset_index()` do, for example? The docs are on the internet, sure, but it takes no time to give a brief explanation, and it helps a lot. Furthermore, I'd like to ask again: why is installing pandas better than using plain python? It's a great package, that's for sure, but it's huge, and it takes a long time to install, plus some dependencies not everyone has. Sometimes you need to consider the context when answering. OP is not doing data science, just writing a simple script. Pandas is not suitable.

Comment: Maybe I'm the one out of the knowledge here, but what dependancies does pandas have? Additionally, *open command prompt**type "pip install pandas"* *press enter*. Wow, I'm out of breathe just thinking of all those action. Using pandas does not delay your code when all you are trying to do is convert this csv to a dict

Comment: That might me my fault, I've probably confused it with a different package which does have certain C dependencies not all systems have by default. However, the main points stand: some explanation on why or how your code works is better than no explanation if the user doesn't know how pandas works, and helping the user fix their own code and explain what they're missing is better than rewriting the whole code with no further explanation.

Comment: I'll admit that for some people, comments may be needed if they don't have experience with a package, but I was expecting for code this short, it would be easy to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Do something simple like this:

```py
thisdict = {
    "ref": [],
}
with open("your.csv") as csv_fp:
    for line in csv_fp:
        if line.startswith("ref"):
            # skip first line
            continue

        ref, col, _, _, content = line.strip().split(",")

        if int(ref) not in thisdict["ref"]:
            thisdict["ref"].append(int(ref))

        if col not in thisdict:
            thisdict[col] = [content]
        else:
            thisdict[col].append(content)

print(thisdict)
```